# Visual Studio 2010 hierachy of solutions - is this possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

We have a big project broken up by concerns, each concern has it's own VS2010 solution - all good.

For the purposes of having just one top level solution to open so an entire system rebuild can be done, I'd like a top level solution that includes the lower level solutions.

It doesn't seem to be possible - all I can do is add projects from the lower level solutions meaning I pretty much have to do that twice.

Is there a better way to manage this, and if so, what?

Comment: How many projects are in each solution? Sounds like you really want a single solution, and just sort the projects within it.

Comment: There are 5 "concerns" each with about 5 projects. So that's 25. (Also a matching unit test project for each one). I don't think I want to have a single project, it's too much to manage at once.

Comment: I said single *solution*, not *project*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no hierarchy for solutions. The only option is to add the individual projects into one solution.

It sounds to me like you have *way* too many projects. The only level of hierarchy you should need is a solution grouping together multiple projects. Use folders to hierarchize within projects.

Beyond that, you shouldn't have to even open up Visual Studio to create a build, so there's really no need for a solution at all. Investigate writing and using a build script to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, the direction answer is no. But, solution folders may be what you are looking for. They allow you to group projects into virtual folders.

However, the VS option of selecting the file in solution explorer when its edit window is selected does not work if the file is in a solution folder that is collapsed. An annoying but small problem.